# ANTLR 4 lexer tokens inside other tokens

Tags: antlr4

I have the following grammar for ANTLR 4:

```
grammar Pattern;

//parser rules
parse   : string LBRACK CHAR DASH CHAR RBRACK ;
string  : (CHAR | DASH)+ ;

//lexer rules
DASH    : '-' ;
LBRACK  : '[' ;
RBRACK  : ']' ;
CHAR    : [A-Za-z0-9] ;
```

And I'm trying to parse the following string

```
ab-cd[0-9]
```

The code parses out the `ab-cd` on the left which will be treated as a literal string in my application. It then parses out `[0-9]` as a character set which in this case will translate to any digit. My grammar works for me except I don't like to have `(CHAR | DASH)+` as a parser rule when it's simply being treated as a token. I would rather the lexer create a `STRING` token and give me the following tokens:

```
"ab-cd" "[" "0" "-" "9" "]"
```

instead of these

```
"ab" "-" "cd" "[" "0" "-" "9" "]"
```

I have looked at other examples, but haven't been able to figure it out. Usually other examples have quotes around such string literals or they have whitespace to help delimit the input. I'd like to avoid both. Can this be accomplished with lexer rules or do I need to continue to handle it in the parser rules like I'm doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ANTLR 4, you can use lexer modes for this.

```
STRING : [a-z-]+;
LBRACK : '[' -> pushMode(CharSet);

mode CharSet;

DASH : '-';
NUMBER : [0-9]+;
RBRACK : ']' -> popMode;
```

After parsing a `[` character, the lexer will operate in mode `CharSet` until a `]` character is reached and the `popMode` command is executed.

Comment: Thanks for this insight. Setting up subtokenizers like this sounds like the perfect solution. I am getting an error though stating `lexical modes are only allowed in lexer grammars`. I can declare my grammar as `lexer grammar IdPattern;`, but then I can't use parser rules. What am I missing?

Comment: You'll need to use a `lexer grammar` for your lexer, and a separate `parser grammar` (in a separate file) for your parser.

Comment: Here is a link that can help others: http://meri-stuff.blogspot.co.za/2011/09/antlr-tutorial-expression-language.html#LexerBasics