# How to parse nested, mini grammar in string using Coco/R?

Tags: c#, parsing, grammar, cocor

I need help constructing the Coco/R grammar to match the following:

```
// Expects "1+2=3" (String concat. No embedded expression)
"1+2="+(1+2)

// Expects "1+2=3" (Embedded expression)
"1+2=%(1+2)"

// Expects "1+2=3" (unlikely, but still valid embedded expression)
"%(pow(0,1-1))+%(sqrt(4))=%(10/2-2)"
```

I'm trying to match embedded expressions in a string (within %())

Here's the grammar that I currently have.

It matches all 3 examples above. But now I have no idea how to continue.

```
COMPILER FooLang

CHARACTERS
    letter = 'a'..'z'.
    digit = '0'..'9'.
    strChar = ANY - '"'.

TOKENS
    ident = letter {letter}.
    number = digit {digit}.
    string = '"' {strChar} '"'.

PRODUCTIONS
    FooLang = expr.
    expr = equ.
    method = ident '(' [ expr {',' expr} ] ')'.
    equ = add { "==" add}.
    add = mul { ('+'|'-') mul }.
    mul = atom { ('*'|'/') atom }.
    atom = number | string | method | '(' expr ')'.

END FooLang.
```

The grammar within %() will be almost the same, but with some differences (ie, no string tokens)

Here's what I've found so far:

1. [Island grammar antlr3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561249/island-grammar-antlr3)
2. [Handling Multiple Language Contexts by Subtractive Context Switching](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/Cookbook/#MCS)
3. [Island Grammars](http://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/IslandGrammars)
4. [ANTLR 4 lexer tokens inside other tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485913/antlr-4-lexer-tokens-inside-other-tokens)

It appears that I want Antlr's "lexer modes", but for Coco/R.

Comment: What does this have to do with C#?

Comment: I'm hoping that perhaps there might be a solution using Coco/R's semantic actions and/or conflict resolvers, which would involve writing C# code (my target language).